# How to have a multiline CSS horizontal scroll?

Tags: html, css

I understand how to do a simple horizontal scroll with elements that are all on the single line.

Single line demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YbrX3/1504/

Although how am I able to do a multiline element scroll with CSS, like so:

```
 1  |  3  |  5  |  7  |  9
---------------------------
 2  |  4  |  6  |  8  |  10
```

Comment: try to set max-width on every row then use overflow:scroll.

Comment: @NelsonTan - What do you mean by every row? As you can see, I don't need rows since it's not 1,2,3,4,5 on the top row.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a solution using a `flexbox`- added this style to `scrolls`:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
height: 160px;
```

I doubled the height of `scrolls` and gave it a `column` flex-direction. Wrapping it gets you the layout you need.

See snippet below:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.scrolls {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 160px;
  white-space: nowrap
}
.scrolls div {
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scrolls">
    <div>
      1
    </div>
    <div>
      2
    </div>
    <div>
      3
    </div>
    <div>
      4
    </div>
    <div>
      5
    </div>
    <div>
      6
    </div>
    <div>
      7
    </div>
    <div>
      8
    </div>
    <div>
      9
    </div>
    <div>
      10
    </div>
    <div>
      11
    </div>
    <div>
      12
    </div>
    <div>
      13
    </div>
    <div>
      14
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: Worked surprisingly well. Thanks!

Comment: there is one problem i am facing, like if i add content in no.1, no.2 takes same width so how can i make it take width as per content ?

Comment: `2` will have the same width as `1` in any case and its expected (even if you use `align-items: flex-start` for instance you will have a gap in the layout see https://jsfiddle.net/jp6Lq4yt/)